# CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'BoughtUpgrade.AvailableUpgrade' to 'AvailableUpgrade'

Tags: c#

I am making Unity Engine based game.
I have 2 classes. One is "BoughtUpgrade" the other is "RotateBase".
Inside "RotateBase" I am trying to save some data and store it inside file "/savedBoughtUpgrades.doma". But when I try to add an object inside List<BoughtUpgrade.AvailableUpgrade> availableUpgradeList which have the same attributes as  List availableUpgradeList. How to convert from one type to another?
Here is my code:

```
public class RotateBase : MonoBehaviour
{    
public List<AvailableUpgrade> availableUpgradeList  = new List <AvailableUpgrade>();

[System.Serializable]
    public class SaveDataUpgrades
    {
        public float coins;
        public List<BoughtUpgrade.AvailableUpgrade> availableUpgradeList = new List<BoughtUpgrade.AvailableUpgrade>();
    }

public void Load()
    {
        string fileLocation02 = Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedBoughtUpgrades.doma";
        if (File.Exists(fileLocation02))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileLocation02, FileMode.Open);
            stream.Position = 0;
            SaveDataUpgrades data = (SaveDataUpgrades)bf.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();

            coins = data.coins;
            //Reads the list and stores values in the original List
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                availableUpgradeList.Add(data.availableUpgradeList[i]); //Error CS1503 shows up here
            }
        }
        else if (!File.Exists(fileLocation02))
        {
            SaveDataUpgrades saveData = new SaveDataUpgrades();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                AvailableUpgrade availableUpgrade = new AvailableUpgrade();
                availableUpgrade.alreadyBoughtUpgradeName = "Tsoko";
                availableUpgrade.alredyBoughtUpgradeAmount = 0;
                availableUpgradeList.Add(availableUpgrade);
            }
            saveData.coins = coins + points;
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileLocation02, FileMode.Create);
            bf.Serialize(stream, saveData);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my other class

```
public class BoughtUpgrade : MonoBehaviour
{
[System.Serializable]
    public class AvailableUpgrade
    {
        public float alreadyBoughtUpgradePrice;
        public float alredyBoughtUpgradeAmount;
        public string alreadyBoughtUpgradeName;
    }

    public RotateBase.SaveDataUpgrades saveData;

 public List<AvailableUpgrade> availableUpgradeList = new List<AvailableUpgrade>();
    public float coins;

public void Save()
        {
        RotateBase.SaveDataUpgrades saveData = new RotateBase.SaveDataUpgrades();
            //saveData.availableUpgradeList = availableUpgradeList;
            //saveData.availableUpgradeList = availableUpgradeList;
            string fileLocation02 = Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedBoughtUpgrades.doma";

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileLocation02, FileMode.Create);
            bf.Serialize(stream, saveData);
            stream.Close();

        }

        public void Load()
        {
            string fileLocation02 = Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedBoughtUpgrades.doma";
            if (File.Exists(fileLocation02))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileLocation02, FileMode.Open);
                stream.Position = 0;
                RotateBase.SaveDataUpgrades data = (RotateBase.SaveDataUpgrades)bf.Deserialize(stream);
                stream.Close();

            //coins = data.coins;
            //Reads the list and stores values in the original List
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                
                //availableUpgradeList.Add(data.availableUpgradeList[i]);
                availableUpgradeList.Add(data.availableUpgradeList[i]);
            }
        }
            else if (!File.Exists(fileLocation02))
            {
            RotateBase.SaveDataUpgrades saveData = new RotateBase.SaveDataUpgrades();

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                BoughtUpgrade.AvailableUpgrade availableUpgrade = new BoughtUpgrade.AvailableUpgrade();
                    availableUpgrade.alreadyBoughtUpgradeName = "Tsoko";
                    availableUpgrade.alredyBoughtUpgradeAmount = 0;
                    availableUpgradeList.Add(availableUpgrade);
                }

            for (int i = 0; i < availableUpgradeList.Count; i++)
            {
                saveData.availableUpgradeList.Add(availableUpgradeList[i]);
            }

            saveData.coins = coins;
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileLocation02, FileMode.Create);
                bf.Serialize(stream, saveData);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: C# is strongly typed: `BoughtUpgrade.AvailableUpgrade` and `AvailableUpgrade` are two separate types. i.e. you cannot automatically assign and object of one type to another. You can e.g. implement conversion constructors, you can implement conversion methods, you can use something like AutoMapper. But the big question is: **_why_** are there two identical definitions of `AvailableUpgrade`? Why not have one and use that in both places?

Comment: Just to clarify  I am new to programming, I thought that I am doing what you said one definition to use in multiple places, but apparently I made a mistake somewhere down the trace. Thank you for the directions  I will try to do what you said and see what will come out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but few common ones that come to mind are:

- Write a method to convert one object to another (there is [a lot of info about this online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions))

  - Brute force example:

    `var availableUpgrades = originList.Select(x => new AvailableUpgrade() { alreadyBoughtUpgradePrice = x.alreadyBoughtUpgradePrice, alredyBoughtUpgradeAmount = x.alredyBoughtUpgradeAmount, alreadyBoughtUpgradeName = x.alreadyBoughtUpgradeName}).ToList();`
- Use some existing mapping nuget/lib to do this

Comment: To me this doesn't seem to be a complete answer to the question... explain the problem and solution. And the last part doesn't really make sense to me...